# Jasmine-Node causing Jenkins to hang after completion

Tags: node.js, jenkins, continuous-integration, jasmine, jasmine-node

I'm having a few problems getting my CI server to play nicely.
I'm running Jenkins to execute a the Jasmine-Node binary on my unit tests using

```
node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node tests/ --junitreport
```

From the output console in Jenkins I can see my tests are being executed successfully.

```
npm info ok 
+ node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node tests/ --junitreport
[32m.[0m[32m.[0m

Finished in 0.33 seconds
[32m2 tests, 9 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped
[0m
```

Although Jenkins never continues any further steps and hangs indefinitely.

Any ideas on how to callback to Jenkins and tell it to continue? I wouldn't have thought it would be necessary, but clearly I am not doing something right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This has now been resolved. Jasmine-Node doesn't terminate after asynchronous specs correctly.
`node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node --forceexit tests/ --junitreport`
using `--forceexit` resolves the problem.